# fragment can not go back to previous state when press Back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-button, android-tablayout

Hi I have a app that follow as follow: `MainActivity` use `navigationDrawer` to navigate between `fragment` for example `fragment1`, `fragment2`, `fragment3`. `Fragment1` Contain `tablayout` `fragment1-A` and child `fragment1-B` and `fragment1-C`. when user in `fragment1-B` click a button, they will go to another `fragment1-B-a` (this transaction will be add to backstack). When user press `backButton` in `fragment1-B-a`. They will go back to `fragment1-B` by these code in the `MainActivity`.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            // if got BackStack, come back to it
            if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()>0) {
                super.onBackPressed();

                // if not come to home screen
            }else {
                if (!homeFlag) {
                    fragment = new MainFragment();
                    fragmentManager.popBackStack();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentMainDrawer, fragment).commit();
                    homeFlag = true;
                } else exit();
            }
        }
    }
```

But when user inside `fragment1-B-a` (2nd `tablayout` `fragment`) if they press `BackButton`. It give the error and crash the app (inside `fragment1-B-a` press `backButton` work normally)

this is the error. Anyhelp is much appreciate. Thanks.

```
12-31 12:20:22.118 9719-9719/victory1908.nlbstafflogin2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: victory1908.nlbstafflogin2, PID: 9719
                                                                          java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
                                                                              at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                              at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.getTabAt(TabLayout.java:448)
                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(TabLayout.java:1759)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageSelected(ViewPager.java:1794)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:548)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:514)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1320)
                                                                              at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:14564)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3157)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3163)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3163)
                                                                              at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:14542)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:468)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1094)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:958)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1666)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:586)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:169)
                                                                              at victory1908.nlbstafflogin2.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:134)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2550)
                                                                              at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3159)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2805)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:224)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2429)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4508)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4463)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4020)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4073)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4039)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4153)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4047)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4210)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4020)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4073)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4039)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4047)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4020)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4073)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4039)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4186)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4347)
                                                                              at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2480)
                                                                              at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2074)
                                                                              at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2065)
                                                                            at android.view.inputmetho
```

Comment: Can you please post your line number 169.

Comment: you mean this two line?  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:169)
                                                                                at victory1908.nlbstafflogin2.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:134) (first is on default FragmentActivity.java class. second is my mainactivity line super.OnbackPress

Comment: yes. Please post this two lines from your code.

Comment: Hi first line is from the default package FragmentActivity.class. second is from my MainActivity: if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()>0) {
                super.onBackPressed();

Answer (score 0):

- Store fragment name is public static variable lastFragment...
- update it whenever moving to new fragment by setting its previous fragment ....
- make it null in main activity ...
  -exit app if it is null otherwise replace fragmentmanger with lastFragment.

Comment: thanks for your respond. Can u give more detail how to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got your problem. This is because `getBackStackEntryCount()` is returning Zero.
So you need to add below lines after committing your fragment `onBackPressed` Button.

```
fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

and add

**fragmentManager(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)** instead of  **fragmentManager.popBackStack();**

`FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE`) is usedto pop the entire back stack.

See this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/0qXCA9rW7EI)

**Editing in your code :**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            // if got BackStack, come back to it
            if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()>0) {
                super.onBackPressed();

                // if not come to home screen
            }else {
                if (!homeFlag) {
                    fragment = new MainFragment();
                   fragmentManager(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)// Change
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentMainDrawer, fragment).commit();
fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();// Change
                    homeFlag = true;
                } else exit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: So that mean instead of using super.onBackPress; we ll use fragmentManager(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE) instead of fragmentManager.popBackStack(); and then fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions(); if not where to put these code?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can u make the code block clear? I got error this line fragmentManager(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)// Change. And also the app crash when go to super.OnbackPress;

Comment: remove super.OnbackPress

Comment: But for this 2 line if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()>0) {
                super.onBackPressed(); if remove super.OnBackPress. user insinde fragment 1-C-a press BackButton. They can not go anywhere as backstackEntry not zero

Comment: Coz we have if else clause

Comment: this line seem to be error FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE;// Change

Comment: I thinks the problem is with the tablayout. Even if remove all the onBachPress it still error. May be can not get to state when in 2nd tab fragment. 1 fragment is ok

Comment: Your error is because of  getBackStackEntryCount() is returning Zero.

Comment: a bit strange as if user in 1-B-a and press backButton work normally (come to 1-B). but when in 1-C-a press backButton, app crash

Comment: See stacktrace for that

Comment: hi where is the stacktrace one. I'm still stuck with this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99448/discussion-between-kishudroid-and-le-khanh-vinh).